# How To: Overwriting all Html.TextBox - ascx not called! Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How can I add to ALL textboxes in ALL aspx sites, like:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Firstname, new { style = "float: left; width: 4.1em;", maxlength = "4" })%>
```

a javascript function without searching them and adding manually something like:

```
new { onkeyup='Foo(this); return false;' }
```

Idea: Writing an `ascx` like the following one!

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%: Html.TextBox(   string.Empty, 
                    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, 
                    new { onkeyup = "foo(this); return false;" })%>
```

Please let us say this `ascx` is named `Test.ascx`
and that it is stored in `\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\`.

My problem is that "Test.ascx" isnt called.
Why?
Must a reference be added to all aspx sites?
Is there a `< System.String>` in the Inherit missing?

Any help would be fine.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your custom editor template to be called you need to use:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firstname) %>
```

and not:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Firstname, new { style = "float: left; width: 4.1em;", maxlength = "4" })%>
```

By using Html.TextBoxFor you are explicitly hardcoding this value and that you want an `<input type="text" ...` and you cannot override or replace it. That's the reason why it is good practice to use `Html.EditorFor` as it allows you to modify the way this is rendered by defining a custom template in the `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates` folder.

Now if you editor template is called: `Test.ascx` you could invoke it like this:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firstname, "Test") %>
```

or by decorating your view model property with the [`[UIHint]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[UIHint("Test")]
public string Firstname { get; set; }
```

and then simply:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firstname) %>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a million for the explanation! I tried it and the Test.ascx is now called and I can add the js/jquery function there. But the original attributes new { style = "float: left; width: 4.1em;", maxlength = "4" } are lost! I will create a new question about that! But you helped me really a lot! Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135210/how-to-avoid-that-an-ascx-tempalte-overwrites-the-original-style-class-maxlengt