# How To avoid that an ascx template overwrites the original style, class, maxlength, etc. attributes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Main issue: Adding to all(!) textboxes in a MVC2 solution/project a js/jquery method.
Basics: How to call an ascx template?
[Solved, see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126696/how-to-overwriting-all-html-textbox-ascx-not-called-why)
(Thanks to Darin Dimitrov!)

**BUT...**

Means the ascx template "Test.ascx" will be called like here shown:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firstname, "Test", new { style = "float: left; width: 4.1em;", maxlength = "4" })%>
```

The "Test.ascx" template adds the js/jquery function.
Works fine, np so fare.
**But:** The "original" attributes `style="..." maxlength="..."` will be lost/overwritten.

My current solution / my "Test.ascx" file:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<input type="text" 
         id="<%: ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty) %>"
       name="<%: ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix %>"
      value="<%: ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue %>" 
      style="<%: ViewData["style"] %>"
      class="<%: ViewData["class"] %>"
  maxlength="<%: ViewData["maxlength"] %>"
    onkeyup="Foo(this); return false;"/>
```

This works really fine and returns / renders it perfectly:

```
<input type="text" 
         id="Firstname"
       name="Firstname"
      value="" 
      style="float: left; width: 4.1em;"
      class=""
  maxlength="4"
    onkeyup="Foo(this); return false;"/>
```

Note that here are the `style="..."` and `maxlength="..."` attributes are well handled!
I use currently the "standard" `< input ... />` tag because I didnt get this to work:

```
<%
    String tmpConfig = " new {onkeyup=\"Foo(this); return false;\"";

    String style = this.ViewData["style"] as String;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(style))
        tmpConfig += ", style=\"" + style + "\"";

    String @class = this.ViewData["class"] as String;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(@class))
        tmpConfig += ", class=\"" + @class + "\"";

    String maxlength = this.ViewData["maxlength"] as String;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(maxlength))
        tmpConfig += ", maxlength=\"" + maxlength + "\"";

    tmpConfig += " } ";
%>

<!-- doesnt work: -->
<%: Html.TextBox(   string.Empty,
                    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
                    // new { onkeyup = "Foo(this); return false;" }    // the style, class, maxlength attributes will be lost / not rendered!
                    // new { tmpConfig }    // result would be the attribut: tempConfig=" onkeyup..."
                    // new tmpConfig        // result: error, tmpConfig isnt object
                    Html.Encode(tmpConfig)  // doesnt work ...
                )%>
```

This renders finally the same but WITHOUT the `style="..."` and `maxlength="..."` attributes!

But I want to use the `<%: Html.TextBox(...) %>` instead of the `< input ... />` tag!
Because this would give me the possibility to avoid an empty attribute like `class=""` and like before shown.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To: Overwriting all Html.TextBox - ascx not called! Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126696/how-to-overwriting-all-html-textbox-ascx-not-called-why)

Comment: No, not double. The first question is about "how to call an ascx template" and here I am asking how to avoid overwriting the "original" attributes (style, maxlength, ...). Please read my post(s). Thanks!

Comment: can you add the current output of the generated html for this textbox and then tell what you would expect to be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to supply the Html.TextBox with a dictionary of String,Object to hold all attributes

```
    <%
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    String style = this.ViewData["style"] as String;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(style))
        dict.Add("style", style);

    String @class = this.ViewData["class"] as String;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(@class))
        dict.Add("class", @class);

    String maxlength = this.ViewData["maxlength"] as String;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(maxlength))
        dict.Add("maxlength", maxlength);

    dict.Add("onkeyup", "Foo(this); return false;");
%>

<%: Html.TextBox(   string.Empty,
                    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
                    dict
                )%>
```